# What are the chances of degree revoke if an unrelated plagiarized paper was published during the course of Phd studies

Tags: plagiarism

The Phd Thesis and course work all are un-plagiarized; degree completed through all the normal procedures of the university.
However, a plagiarized research paper which is un-related to the doctoral thesis and coursework was published during the PhD tenure.

What are the chances of degree revoke (the degree has long been granted).

Regards.

Comment: Very slim chance, though it might depend on circumstances. Can you retract/correct the paper? And what some fear is plagiarism is really just sloppy scholarship or other errors of a less serious nature.

Comment: the plagiarized paper is heavily plagiarized (I always regret that time of doing it).... can you please explain 'though it might depend on circumstances'.

Comment: it must be added here that the plagiarized paper has no match for the scope and field of study of doctoral dissertation.

Comment: I would like if anyone has ever seen such a case.

Comment: If ever such a case happened, please share the details.

Answer (score 2):

It can happen.  But it would depend a lot on the policies at that institution.  As [reported in the New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2014/10/11/us/politics/plagiarism-costs-degree-for-senator-john-walsh.html), consider the case of Senator John Walsh (D-MT), whose master's degree from the US Army War College was revoked when it was discovered that he had plagiarized a paper he'd submitted in partial satisfaction of his degree requirements *seven years* earlier.  They even ground his name off the bronze plaque listing the school's graduates.

Comment: Thanks for a reply. It must be mentioned here that the plagiarized paper has not been referred to as a part of partial satisfaction of degree requirement. It was a stand alone incident.